# Обработка событий сквозь объект

Tags: c++, ооп, c++builder

Есть у меня два класса, оба наследуются от `TImage`
В объекте первого класса есть указатель на объект второго класса картинка у него рл размеру меньше)
Когда я нажимаю на объект первого класса, срабатывает его обработчик `OnClick` и создаётся объект второго класса, который почти полностью перекрывает первый объект
Когда я снова нажимаю на объект первого класса, объект второго класса должен удалится, но из-за своего размера, мне приходится нажимать на край первого объекта
Можно как-то сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на объект первого класса объект второго класса игнорировался, так сказать, чтобы обработчик отловил событие сквозь второго объекта

Comment: Проще пристрелить второй объект и не мучиться. Как говорил товарищ Сталин, есть человек - есть проблема. Нет человека - нет проблемы.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow да, но мне нужно чтобы первый объект знал о том, что второй уничтожен. В таком случае должна меняться картинка первого объекта

Answer (score 0):

Эндрю, на СиБилдере программил достаточно давно, посему - кодом тебя не обеспечу. Но рекомендации дам, и уверен, они тебе помогут.

> Можно как-то сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на объект первого класса объект второго класса игнорировался, так сказать, чтобы обработчик отловил событие сквозь второго объекта?

Поход неверный

**Имеем**

- Объект класса "A"
- Объект класса "В", который является "потомком" объекта класса "A", и частично может его перекрывать
- Объект класса "В" находится "выше" по Z-координате объекта класса "A"

**Обеспечиваем**

- У всех объектов есть поле ссылки на "родителя"
- У всех объектов есть поле списка (массива) на потомков

Этим обеспечивается коммуникация GUI-объектов, в иных терминах - виджетов.

**Передаем**

- Один из виджетов словил клик на координате (x,y)
- По условиям вопроса данный виджет должен вызвать у "родителя" обработчик, иными словами - "прокинуть". А соответствующий указатель у нас есть.
- Что может сказать "родитель"? "Сделано" или "Обрабатывай сам"
- Что может сделать "родитель"? 1) Сделать самому, 2) Отдать задачу "другим потомкам", "Отказаться"